# Where is the best place for LUKS to sit in a RAID/LVM/LUKS stack?

Tags: linux, security, lvm, software-raid

I am implementing a server storage setup making use of software RAID, LVM and LUKS.

I can think of three combinations this configuration could take:

1. RAID, LVM, LUKS
2. RAID, LUKS, LVM
3. LUKS, RAID, LVM

In which order would these best be configured in, where best is in terms of security and maintainability?

Answer (score 2):

I would make the RAID array first because when you will change a disk of the array, it will be tranparent for LUKS and LVM.

If there is no need to keep some partition unencrypted (except for the /boot partition), I would setup LUKS in second because I don't want to have to setup LUKS every time I make a change in my partitions.